# JAVA Transformer adding spaces and single quotes to XML header and not encoding the resulting XML file?

Tags: java, xml, encoding, jaxb, xml-signature

I have the following JAXB marshaller that is using a DOM result in order to add XML Digital Signature later on:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataPDU.class);
DataPDU myDataPDU = new DataPDU();
myDataPDU.setRevision("2.0.6");

// marshall the file
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

DOMResult domResult = new DOMResult();
marshaller.marshal(myDataPDU, domResult);

// get the document list
Document document = (Document) domResult.getNode();

// create the output file
File kadSignatureOutputFile = new File("pptExampleTest.xml");

// create the file output stream to be used in the XSL transformation
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(kadSignatureOutputFile);

// create the factory and the transformer
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();

// set the document to print the out with indent and UTF-8 encoded
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

// transform the DOM source to a stream source (i.e the file we are in)
trans.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(os));
```

I have some problems here, the output file is not being encoded in UTF-8, even though the encoding is set to UTF-8 but in notepad++ it is not being marked as encoded and the software provides an option to convert the file to utf-8.

> How to make sure the file is properly encoded when it is transformed
>   by the JAVA API?

Another thing, the xml header attribute values are being single quoted and have space between the attribute name and value, I am not sure if this tag (the XML header) will be considered when signing the document later on, but if it does this is gonna be a big problem.

> How to obtain the standard XML header with double quotes and no spaces
>   using transformers?

Result:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
```

Expectation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: For the encoding problem, maybe `trans.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("pptExampleTest.xml"), "utf-8")));` helps by setting the output encoding. For the other issue: what java version are you using?

Comment: Didn't really help, I am using JDK7.

Comment: What is the concrete class name of the object returned by `TransformerFactory.newInstance()`? There are multiple implementations of this method and we need to know which one you are picking up.

Comment: Note that the XML declaration you are seeing is perfectly legal, though it's a bit unusual, and it's certainly possible that poor-quality software looking for the XML declaration might not recognize it in this form.

Comment: @MichaelKay The concrete class name is `JXSAXTransformerFactory`

Comment: Thanks. That's not one I'm familiar with. It appears to be part of the Oracle XDK (which is not renowned as the best). You could work around the problem by loading a different implementation explicitly, for example put Saxon-HE on the classpath and do `TransformerFactory tf = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl()`.

Comment: @MichaelKay, this actually worked, thanks. Do you think we can find to ensure the created file is actually UTF-8 encoded?