# transformer.setOutputProperty() is not taking effect - java 8

Tags: xml, apache-poi, transformer-model

I'm using poi library to write xml file using transformer and I have these properties sat:

java 1.8

```
//for output to file, console
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        //for pretty print
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC, "yes"); //TODO
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");     
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
```

But the result appears with standalone="no" and without spacing/indentation!!!

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<MainStruct>
<StringArray1 value="H1"/>
<StringArray1 value="H1"/>
<StringArray1 value="H1"/>
<StringArray1 value="H1"/>
<Table>
<IntVar1 value="1"/>
<StringVar1 value="String1"/>
<IntVar2 value="2"/>
<StringVar2 value="S"/>
</Table>
.
.
```

Expected:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' standalone = 'yes'?>
<MainStruct>
   <StringArray1 value="H1"/>
   <StringArray1 value="H1"/>
   <StringArray1 value="H1"/>
   <StringArray1 value="H1"/>
   <Table>
      <IntVar1 value="1"/>
      <StringVar1 value="String1"/>
      <IntVar2 value="2"/>
      <StringVar2 value="S"/>
   </Table>
.
.
```

Comment: Following this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43754776/java-transformer-adding-spaces-and-single-quotes-to-xml-header-and-not-encoding?rq=1 I used "Saxon" and it solved it. Seems that the problem is with Oracle JDK

Comment: Alternately you can use IBM java instead, it's working fine with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the transformer how big the indents are:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
```